# Deduction of $H^\star(RP^\infty,Z)=Z[x]/(2x),|x|=2$ from $H^\star(RP^\infty, Z_2)=Z_2[y],|y|=1$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

This is a statement made in Hatcher, Algebraic Topology Chpt 3, Sec 2.

One can compute $H^\star(RP^\infty,Z_2)=Z_2[y]$ with $|y|=1$. Now from cellular cochain complex $C^\star(RP^\infty, Z)\to C^\star(RP^\infty, Z_2)$ obtained by projection map $Z\to Z_2$, one deduces $H^\star(RP^\infty, Z)\to H^\star(RP^\infty, Z_2)$ being injection.(It is easy to see $Z\to Z_p$ always inducing chain complex morphism and a cocycle is pushed to a cocycle under chain complex morphism. Checking injectivity is easy then.) Then one deduces $H^\star(RP^\infty,Z)=Z[x]/(2x)$ with $|x|=2$.

Then the book says "Alternatively, this could be deduced from universal coefficient theorem."

$\textbf{Q1:}$ How do I deduce $Z$ valued cohomology from $Z_2$ valued cohomology via universal coefficient theorem?(It is possible to deduce from $Z_2$ cohomology from $Z$ cohomology under universal coefficient theorem. Normally, I would expect somehow patching all primes $p$ of $Z_p$ valued cohomology to $Z$ cohomology which I do not know it is true in general.)

$\textbf{Q2:}$ Why do I expect $H^\star(RP^\infty,Z)=Z[x]/(2x)$ with $|x|=2$ whereas $H^\star(RP^\infty,Z_2)=Z_2[y]$ with $|y|=1$? By computation, one sees $|x|=2$. I do not see why $|x|=2$ is intuitively obvious though $|y|=1$ is obviously true as there is non-trivial cell complex there which is quotient of sphere but $Z_2$ does not see reflection. What is geometric interpretation of $|x|=2$ here? Certainly $Z$ coefficient will see reflection.

Comment: I don't think it's true because you have no information about non-$2$-torsion in $H^*(-;\mathbb Z)$ from $H^*(-,\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)$. For instance, $\mathbb RP^\infty \times K(\mathbb Z/3, 1)$ has the same mod $2$ cohomology as $\mathbb RP^\infty$ but not the same integral cohomology.

Comment: @Max Sure. Then I do not know what does he mean here? The book was trying to deduce $Z$ cohomology from $Z_2$ due to injectivity which sees all 2-torsion for sure and it happens that $Z$ cohomology has only 2 torsion. So for such kind of argument, one can only see $2$-torsion component of cohomology then? Is this correct?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "due to injectivity" : there's no injectivity in degree $0$ for instance. Of course if you can prove that in positive degrees, $H^k(\mathbb RP^\infty, \mathbb Z)$ has only $2$-torsion, then you can use the universal coefficient theorem to get the $2$-torsion of $H_k(\mathbb RP^\infty, \mathbb Z)$ and use that to get $H^k$ by again applying the UCT

Comment: @Max Sorry that I was too lazy to be specific. Injective only in the positive graded components. The degree $0$ part is easy to identify.

Comment: So is what you meant "knowing the injectivity, how do you get the cohomology exactly ?" ?

Comment: @Max For degree $0$, that is what it is. For higher degree component, you know it is embedding as you can check only odd components vanishing over $Z-$coefficients and even components will have generator of positive degree cohomology over $Z$ sent to generators of positive degree cohomology over $Z_2$. Then the cup structure is identified on positive degree components.

Comment: But then I don't understand your problem ?

Comment: @Max I have two problems. 1. I thought the book means to somehow use universal coefficient to deduce $Z$ cohomology from $Z_2$ cohomology which does not seem to be the case. 2. Why $|x|=2$ for $Z$ cohomology? I am looking for a geometric answer without going thru computation.

Comment: Ok well as I said for 1. : if you know injectivity, then you can in fact use the UCT to conclude, if you don't then you can't